# Indexing values in a combo box

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am trying to write a code where I am generating all the sheets of a workbook in a combobox in a userform using the code:

```
'List all sheets in combobox
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
            Me.ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets(i).Name
        Next
        Me.ComboBox1.Value = ActiveSheet.Name
```

I then want to use the value that is selected to add data to that page. Is there a way to reference the sheets without having to hard code the reference as:

```
If ComboBox1.Value = "Overview" Then
   sheets1.Activate
End If
```

When I try using the code:

```
ComboBox1.Value = SheetName

Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
```

I get a runtime error 9.

Comment: `SheetName = Combobox1.Value`  you had it backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding comment as answer:

You need to set your variable (sheetname) value, so variable = what comprises the variable:

```
SheetName = Combobox1.Value
```

Your error 9 is probably because you are referencing `Worksheet()` since you haven't set a value to sheetname.